# IEnumerable<string> foreach returns all pages in result; foreach instead of for loop

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I want to return string output for 3 pages but instead program outputs one page 3 times. I already realize "for loop" implementation that works but I wanna use foreach.

```
namespace Itext5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\500indycar-race-results.pdf");
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\191.pdf");                       
            IEnumerable<string> GetColumnText(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury)

            {
                int get_PageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
                var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
                var renderFilter = new RenderFilter[1];
                renderFilter[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
                var textExtractionStrategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderFilter);

                for (int pagecount = 1; pagecount <= get_PageNum; pagecount++)
                {
                    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pagecount, textExtractionStrategy);
                    yield return text;
                }
            }

            foreach (string result in GetColumnText(0, 0, 500, 500000))
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats the question? Just build a string and then print it, i.e. move your console.write outside of your loop

Comment: No. I can bulld string but I have 3 pages pdf document. A wanna output all page not 1 pages 3 or 2 times.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: I think you mean this, `var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, get_PageNum, textExtractionStrategy);` you set `text` to the same thing all the time. How you change that depends on what `PdfTextExtractor` is and what you want this to do, which isn't clear. I'd **guess** you should put the call to `GetColumnText` inside your `foreach`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just learning. This is logical. I need to recheck code deeply.

Comment: @Liam,  I change code in topic but could not get proper result. O, I just get it and found something)) I would do it

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because I **think** your trying to put an answer into the question. Undo if I'm incorrect

Answer (score -2):

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Itext5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\191.pdf");
            IEnumerable<string> GetColumnText(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury)

            {
                int get_PageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (int pagecount = 1; pagecount <= get_PageNum; pagecount++)
                {
                    var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
                    var renderFilter = new RenderFilter[1];
                    renderFilter[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
                    var textExtractionStrategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderFilter);
                    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pagecount, textExtractionStrategy);
                    yield return text;
                }
            }

            foreach (string result in GetColumnText(0, 0, 500, 500000))
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or are you trying to edit the question?

Comment: Both! Thank you! I need to be more concentrate and attentive

Comment: How can it be an answer and an edit?! You're not really making a lot of sense here?

Comment: Cause I do not wanna stole bad example